# Multiple instances of jquery plugin, new settings

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have created a new jquery plugin based on the OO principals. The plugin should be able to have multiple instances with each their own settings/options. however, the way I've now implemented it, the first setting is the one used for all instances.

I can't seem to find the solution for this:

I open it:

```
// the semi-colon before the function invocation is a safety 
// net against concatenated scripts and/or other plugins 
// that are not closed properly
; (function ($, window, document, undefined) {
```

I do the following functions:

```
    /**
    * Method for formatting a certain amount inside a provided element 
    * (the element can be an input or a regular span).
    *
    * @param object element         : Where the value will come from.
    * @param array options              : The different options to format     the amount. The options are culture, valuta and the amount of rounding.
    *
    * @return void;
    */
var AmountFormatter = function (element, options) {
    var elem = $(element);
    var self = this;

    //Defaults in case a value is missing
    var defaults = {
        culture: "",
        currency: "",
        rounding: 2
    };  

    // jQuery has an extend method that merges the 
    // contents of two or more objects, storing the 
    // result in the first object. The first object 
    // is generally empty because we don't want to alter 
    // the default options for future instances of the plugin
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options || {});
    self._settings = settings;

    //Various functions

            //Start using the amountFormatter, this is a public function, so if you want to use the logic without a jquery selector, you can :).
    this.init = function (elements) {

        //If you the plugin is accessed with a jquery selector, format it as followed:
        if (elements instanceof jQuery) {
            //Check the value of each element and update it accordingly
            elements.each(function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var elementIsInput = $this.is("input");

                value = $this.val() == "" ? $this.text().trim() : $this.val().trim();
                if(typeof value === 'undefined' || value === "") {
                    return ""; 
                }
                value = thousandSeperator(convertNumber(roundingOfNumber(value, self._settings.rounding)));

                //Checks whether we need to add the new amount as text or as a value
                return elementIsInput === true ?
                    elem.val(addCurrencyToNumber(value)) :
                    elem.text(addCurrencyToNumber(value));
            });
        }
        //Otherwise we:
        else {
            //First of, check if the provided variable is at least set and has at least one element
            if (elements != undefined || elements != null || elements.length !== 0) {
                if (elements instanceof Array) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i) {
                        var value = elements[i].toString();
                        elements[i] = addCurrencyToNumber(thousandSeperator(convertNumber(roundingOfNumber(value, self._settings.rounding))));
                    }
                    return elements;
                }
                else {
                    var value = elements.toString();
                    return addCurrencyToNumber(thousandSeperator(convertNumber(roundingOfNumber(value, self._settings.rounding))));
                }
            }
        }
    };


    this.init(elem);
};
```

Here, I initialize the amountFormatter:

```
/*
* Initialize the amountFormatter
*/
$.fn.amountFormatter = function (options) {
    return this.each(function () {          
        var $this = $(this);            

        if ($this.data('amountFormatter')) return;

        var amountFormatter = new AmountFormatter($this, options);
        $this.data('amountFormatter', amountFormatter);
    });
};
```

And then I just close it:

```
})(jQuery, window, document);
```

How I use it on my page:

First instance:

```
        // With options...
        container.amountFormatter({
            culture: "NL",                   
            currency:  "€",
            rounding: decimals
        });

        //Initiate the plugin and add the array to the list...
        var amountFormatterData = container.data('amountFormatter');
```

Second instance:

```
// With options...
        container.amountFormatter({
            culture: "NL",                   
            currency:  " ",
            rounding: decimals
        });

//Initiate the plugin and add the array to the list...
        var amountFormatterData = container.data('amountFormatter');
```

So the second instance takes the values of the first instance and I can't seem to make it so that each instance uses their own settings of they have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found it already. But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Where I Initialize the amountFormatter, I do a check of the data stored as 'amountFormatter'. If it's already created after the first time the amountformatter is initialized, it takes that data and does a return:

```
if ($this.data('amountFormatter')) return;
```

So removing the above lines, fixed it. Now I always create a new instance of the amountformatter. I'm now most likely going to update this further and see if I can provide the option to let the user choose.

Comment: try to use settings rather than self._settings